# Pandas - groupby column then specify condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
   Batch   Fruit  Property1  Property2  Property3
0      1   Apple         38         55         52
1      1  Banana         59         37         47
2      1   Pear          62         34         25
3      2   Apple         95         64         48
4      2  Banana         10         84         39
5      2   Pear          16         87         38
6      3   Apple         29         34         49
7      3  Banana         27         41         51
8      3   Pear          35         33         17
```

For the dataframe, I want to add a column 'Status', which can have the value 'keep' or 'remove'.
The condition is that all Fruits within Batch have column 'Status' == keep when:

1. Apple has all Property1 < 30, Property2 < 40, Property3 < 50
2. Banana has all Property1 < 35, Property2 < 45, Property3 < 55
3. Pear has all Property1 < 37, Property2 < 46, Property3 < 53

Results should look like:

```
   Batch   Fruit  Property1  Property2  Property3 Status 
0      1   Apple         38         55         52  remove
1      1  Banana         59         37         47  remove
2      1   Pear          62         34         25  remove
3      2   Apple         95         64         48  remove
4      2  Banana         10         84         39  remove
5      2   Pear          16         87         38  remove
6      3   Apple         29         34         49    keep
7      3  Banana         27         41         51    keep
8      3   Pear          35         33         17    keep
```

Comment: Is the status "keep" when any of the conditions are satisfied or all three are satisfied? For example, if the condition for apple is satisfied but the condition for banana isn't for some batch, do you keep the batch or remove it?

Comment: yes, if the condition for at least 1 fruit is 'remove' in a batch, then all fruits in the batch should have status 'remove'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
    df['Status']='remove'
    df['Status']=np.where((df['Property1']<30)&(df['Property2']<40)&(df['Property3']<50)&(df['Fruit']=='Apple'),'keep',df['Status'])
    df['Status']=np.where((df['Property1']<35)&(df['Property2']<45)&(df['Property3']<55)&(df['Fruit']=='Banana'),'keep',df['Status'])
    df['Status']=np.where((df['Property1']<37)&(df['Property2']<46)&(df['Property3']<53)&(df['Fruit']=='Pear'),'keep',df['Status'])
```

Comment: This approach requires multiple sweeps of the dataframe - Ok for a small df which this is likely the case. But this will be problematic when `N` is large. +1 for the small cases!

Comment: Could you explain more what you are saying please. I thought np.where was the fastest way to do it

Comment: Np.where is very fast so is an apply function also - you do 3 separate where’s when you can do the same condition setting in a single pass. But for small data frames there will be no noticeable difference - but would be interested if this is not the case.

Comment: This is close to what I want. If there is at least once "remove" in a Batch, then all other rows within that batch should also have status 'Remove'.

Answer (score 3):

```
def condition(x):
    if (x['Property1']<30)&(x['Property2']<40)&(x['Property3']<50)&(x['Fruit']=='Apple'):
        return "Keep"
    elif (x['Property1']<35)&(x['Property2']<45)&(x['Property3']<55)&(x['Fruit']=='Banana'):
        return "Keep"
    elif (x['Property1']<37)&(x['Property2']<46)&(x['Property3']<53)&(x['Fruit']=='Pear'):
        return "Keep"
    
    else:
        return "Remove"
 
df['test'] = df.apply(condition, axis=1)
```